# For my quiz app how I can I match the answer and increase the count if it is correct?

Tags: android, json

*I am fetching JSON data*

JSON data is as below:

```
        {  
  "results":[  
  {  
     "id":4,
     "ps":"Besides gases, air also contains",
     "op1":"Smoke",
     "op2":"Water vapour",
     "op3":"Dust particles",
     "op4":"All of these",
     "resType":"multiple",
     "ans1":null,
     "ans2":null,
     "ans3":null,
     "ans4":"Yes",}......
       .......
```

I am storing all received data in ArrayList as below:

```
        questionList = new ArrayList<String>();
        opList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        opList2 = new ArrayList<>();
        opList3 = new ArrayList<>();
        opList4 = new ArrayList<>();

        answer1 = new ArrayList<>();
         .........................
         .........................
```

on each button click I have done something like this:

```
        Button op1, op2, op3, op4;    
        int count;(GLobal)

       public void onClick(View v) {                   

       String message = op4.getText().toString();
       TextView show = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewChoice);

       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), message, 1000).show();
                show.setText(message);

       if (op4.getText().equals("Yes")) {
            count = count + 1;
       } else if (op4.getText().equals("null"))
            count = count;
       }
```

Every time my count is =0

Comment: check op4.getText() value?

Comment: Here your logic is completely wrong!  you must get "ans4" object and then match with condition!

Comment: opList4.add(mcq.get(currentPosition).getOp4());
                op4.setText(mcq.get(currentPosition).getOp4().toString());

Comment: Where you are parsing json data..? can you post that..?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic should like this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  case R.id.op1 :{
   if(ans4.equals("yes")) {
      counter++;
    }
  }
  case R.id.op2 :{
   if(ans2.equals("yes")) {
    counter++;
   }
  }
 }
```